# What is the precision of STK terrain from AGI?

Tags: cesiumjs, terrain

AS we are using STK terrain in CesiumJS, I am wondering what is the precision of the terrain data?

I guess STK is also generated from DEM, and the precision in different parts of the world is definitely different. But is there a specific number? Like DEM data, there is a number like resolution to evaluate the precision. What about it for STK World Terrain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CesiumJS hasn't been using STK World Terrain in over a year, they switched to their own Cesium-ion-based terrain server.  But I believe they seeded it with STK World Terrain (with AGI's permission, as they spun out from AGI) and have been augmenting it little by little since then.

I asked around (internally to AGI) and got this response from someone who works on STK and terrain:

> The resolution of the terrain hosted by the STK Terrain Server (now superceded by Cesium ion and [GCS](https://cesium.com/geospatial-content-server/)) was 3-10m Continential US, 30m between 60N-60S, 1000m otherwise.

So, this means the resolution is variable.  Some areas have higher resolution than others, but this should give some idea of the range available.